# sql plan discrepancy in DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR

Tags: sql, oracle, explain

Running on Oracle 12.1  I am looking for SQL with full table scans in their plans.
When I look in:

```
select * from V$SQL_PLAN where sql_id = '89p47f9wnnwg9'
```

[image]

I get 21 rows back, one of them with TABLE ACCESS FULL

However, if I call this for the same sql _id with:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ( DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR ('89p47f9wnnwg9', 0, 'ALL'))
```

I get results with only 13 rows from the plan table and the TABLE ACCESS FULL is missing.

[image]

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: check the column `CHILD_NUMBER` in V$SQL_PLAN. The above query shows all child cursors, the below only the cursor with child_number = 0

Answer (score 3):

One query string (represented by `SQL_ID`) can have several different execution plans. All are stored in `V$SQL_PLAN` and identified by different `CHILD_NUMBER`.

The function [DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xplan.htm#ARPLS70136) has a second parameter, where you can pass the required child_number. If you omit the second parameter, the function returns all child cursors, so effectively you should see all rows from V$SQL_PLAN (but in different execution plans).

To see which child cursor is actually used, you may check the `V$SESSION` column `SQL_CHILD_NUMBER`.

**Update for 12c**

This obvious answer to the question why has `V$SQL_PLAN` more rows than `DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR`
was the most probable one until 12c version of Oracle. 12c introduced  [Adaptive Query Optimization](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-optimizer-with-oracledb-12c-1963236.pdf)
where some operation are marked by the optimizer as inactive. This choice can be switched by the execution engine.
Such plans can be recognized by the operation `STATISTICS COLLECTOR`. The STATISTICS COLLECTOR tests on execution the actual number of rows
and if it is higher than the from optimize calculated `point of inflection` switches the plan. (Example - nested loops work fine for few rows, but 
for a large number its "hanging"; contrary hash join work good for large number of rows, but for few rows it has a high overhead.
*Point of inflection* should correspond to such number of row, where the costs are estimated the same).

Unfortunately there is no column in `V$SQL_PLAN` identifying the inactive operations.

This [blog](https://martincarstenbach.wordpress.com/2015/01/13/adaptive-plans-and-vsql_plan-and-related-views/) makes observation, that this information could be extracted the the column `OTHER_XML` using the element `display_map` attribute `@skp`

```
 <display_map>
    <row op="1" dis="1" par="0" prt="0" dep="1" skp="0"/>
    <row op="2" dis="2" par="1" prt="0" dep="2" skp="0"/>
    <row op="3" dis="2" par="2" prt="0" dep="2" skp="1"/>
    ....
```

Comment: V$SQL_PLAN.CHILD_NUMBER is 0, and that is what I passed in, and it still does not match. I cannot use V$Session because there may no longer be a record in there. Using V$SQLAREA,

Comment: Posted same question on Oracle site, and got an answer that works: It's an adaptive plan - there are two inflection points (indicated by the STATISTICS COLLETOR) operations where Oracle can make a run-time decision.

change 'ALL' to 'adaptive' in your call to display_cursor and you'll see all the lines and a note explaining how to identify the "inactive" lines

 

Regards

Jonathan Lewis

Comment: @OldProgrammer very sorry for the inappropriate answer. I was mislead with the missing `CHILD_NUMBER` predicate in the query of `V$SQL_PLAN`. I extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per Jonathan Lewis,

It's an adaptive plan - there are two inflection points (indicated by the STATISTICS COLLETOR) operations where Oracle can make a run-time decision.

change 'ALL' to 'adaptive' in your call to display_cursor and you'll see all the lines and a note explaining how to identify the "inactive" lines

Regards
Jonathan Lewis

So

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ( DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR ('89p47f9wnnwg9', null, 'ADAPTIVE'))
```

returns the row, but is flagged as "not used".